# directing a user to a location of files with vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to let a user select a folder from pressing a button in a vba form, but when I press the button it directs me to documents. How would I direct my user to a specific location of files?

here is some of my code

```
   lnkNm = InputBox("please enter link description")
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   fdlgType = 4

   set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(fdlgType)

    With fdlg
    .Title = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Please select an Evidence FILE to link to", _
                               "Please select an Evidence FOLDER to link to")
    .ButtonName = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Select File", "Select Folder")
    .Show
    For Each itm In .SelectedItems
        strFileToLink = itm
          'Checking if file is selected.
        If strFileToLink = vbNullString Then
            'Displaying a message if file not choosen in the above step.
            MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry"
            'And exiting from the procedure.
            Exit Sub
        Else
```

thank you in advance for anyone with help.

Comment: see answer below, you need to set the `.InitialFileName` to your default path (as a String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Path were you want to direct the user, consider that it might be different due to user C:/myuser... so use ENVIRON like this:

```
Const InitialPath = "\Documents"
With fdlg
    .Title = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Please select an Evidence FILE to link to", _
                               "Please select an Evidence FOLDER to link to")
    .ButtonName = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Select File", "Select Folder")
    .Show
    .InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & InitialPath
```

Answer (score 2):

See my code below, it only handles a the part of your code where you add the parameter for default location the File Dialog opens.

```
Dim strPath As String

' modify to your path here
strPath = "C:\Test\"

Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(fdlgType)

With fdlg
    .Title = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Please select an Evidence FILE to link to", _
    "Please select an Evidence FOLDER to link to")
    .ButtonName = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Select File", "Select Folder")

    ' set default path when opening the File Dialog
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    .Show

End With
```

Comment: OT: lol, answered at the exact same time with almost the same answer, what are the odds of that?